# Initiating Multipart Upload to S3 with AWS Javascript SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to initiate a multipart upload to a S3 bucket with a lambda function and eventually upload a large file to the bucket in chunks with pre-signed URLs. I've already successfully uploaded smaller files to my bucket with presigned URLs but when I try to initialize a multipart upload I get an error "Task timed out after 3.00 seconds". From what I can tell looking at documentation and other SO answers I should have everything I need here. Is there anything I'm missing here or is there a way to get an error message instead of a timeout from Lambda?

Here is my lambda function to initiate an upload

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk') // lambda includes aws-sdk

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: process.env.accessKey,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.secretAccessKey
});

exports.startUpload = function(event,context,callback){
    console.log('at start upload') // this outputs fine in logs
    const s3Params = {
        Bucket: 'bucket-name',
        ContentType: event.type,
        Key: event.name
    }
    console.log('here are params')
    console.log(s3Params) // this outputs as I would expect in logs
    s3.createMultipartUpload(s3Params, function(error,response){
        if(error) callback(error)
        console.log('here is response') // logs never get here
        console.log(response)
        callback(null, response)
    })
```

And here is the permission policy on the IAM user I created specifically for uploading files

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is the CORS configuration set on the S3 bucket itself

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>30000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: The default Lambda function timeout is 3 seconds. You can increase this, as needed.

Comment: I tried increasing the function timeout and it just changed the error to "task timed out after X seconds" This should easily be able to finish in 3 seconds and from what i know a timeout error usually means i got one of the permissions wrong

Comment: A timeout almost *never* means you got a permission wrong. Maybe with a username/password kind of login to a service, which just drops your request if it's invalid, but S3/IAM will respond with AccessDenied. On the "should easily be able to finish in 3 seconds" comment, how long does this same operation take from your laptop (outside of Lambda)? And are you running Lambda in a VPC?

Comment: that's good news about permission, good to know thanks.

I just set it up locally and it worked just fine in 582 ms. This is not a viable solution since I don't want to store any AWS IAM credentials on the client. I am confused because when I perform a similar operation (s3.getSignedUrl) from the same SDK in the same lambda function to the same bucket with the same IAM user it completes just fine. Yes I am running this Lambda in a VPC.

Comment: Creating a pre-signed URL requires no API call to AWS; it's a local calculation in the SDK. So, it's not comparable to your upload API calls to the S3 service. Your problem is likely to be that you've set up networking and/or security groups incorrectly and your Lambda function has no network route to S3. Review the documentation for that.

Comment: think you're probably right, thanks for help and sending me down the right path!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680930/aws-lambda-function-with-vpc-only-works-when-in-private-subnet. The most common mistake is deploying Lambda into a public subnet, when it should be into a private subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I thought I had a problem with using the AWS Javascript SDK but it was just a problem with my Lambda function not being connected to the internet since it was set up in a VPC with no public subnet. Fixed this issue by creating a new Lambda function not connected to any of my own VPCs since by default Lambda functions are launched in an AWS managed VPC with internet access. Leaving this here if anyone wants to see a working configuration of initiating a S3 multipart upload in JS. Big thanks to Jarmod for helping